# Are post-2013 US $100 bills widely accepted in Mongolia and worldwide?

Tags: money, exchange, mongolia

I've picked up my currency today, and the US 100 dollar note had a [new look](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_one_hundred-dollar_bill#Small_size_note_history), including a hologram plus it no longer being green. (All of the notes are crisp and clean)

In countries where it's not the national currency, such as Mongolia, is this new note as widely accepted (or even more widely accepted) as older hundred dollar notes amongst those willing to accept hundred dollar notes at all?

Comment: The new bills have been in circulation for almost 3 years. I have heard that in many "3rd world" countries, it's getting hard to use the **old** bills because they are so much easier to counterfit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

People and banks prefer the new notes. Some will not accept the old notes at all.

Edit: To back up my answer: I have been collecting traveler updates from Mongolia and the larger region since 2010. I haven't heard of anyone having their old 100$ notes rejected, but I would not rule it out simply because I haven't heard/experienced it, and I think some kind of rule/habit could come soon to the country. So I advise, anywhere along the Silk Road, always try to travel with new, crisp, unfolded dollars. In Turkmenistan for instance, old 100$ notes are already no longer accepted, and many people across the region are fussy about the condition of the dollars they accept.

Comment: Anything to back this up - links, personal experience (in what countries)?

Comment: @JanDoggen [Caravanistan](http://caravanistan.com/) is **THE resource** on travelling in the wider stans area and what he writes is perfectly backed up with personal experience of not only him but plenty of other travellers on his site (nicely disclosed on his profile page). This answer turned up in the review queue for its shortness I guess but is perfectly valid and good, especially as a general answer for such a broad question. I gave a +1 and I ask the downvoter for clarification.

Comment: @mts - that's all very well, but the duty is on the answer in question to make clear what it's sources are - even if that's "Been spending dollars in Mongolia for the last 6 months"

Comment: @mts I take your word for it, but if readers (like me) don't know him, they see an answer without factual information. And [this *is* a StackExchange site](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/255/faq-proposal-back-it-up-and-dont-repeat-others)

Comment: 7 or 8 years ago when Myanmar was less well connected to the outside than they are now, very new unblemished US $100 bills were pretty much the only thing you could use to buy local currency, which you needed to do a lot since hardly anyone other than higher end hotels accepted credit cards. The first time I went they wouldn't take about a quarter of the bills I brought due to creases or cuts or other imperfections, for the second I got my bank in Hong Kong to order brand new bills for me which made them happier.

Comment: I just approved this edit since I am assume it's you, Caravanistan, and you forgot to log in. Thanks for clarification.